# Can implement buildin server in my application , that support php/asp?

Tags: language-agnostic

i have application that generate php/html/asp web sites and i like to be able to 
let the possibility to test the sites from within the application . is there any possibility to do that ?

Comment: In order to be able to provide a meaningful answer it would be good to know what language and framweworks you application uses in order to determine how you could embed a webserver with php or asp support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing a web site is a pretty complicated task.  While you could certainly write a web server and test engine, I'm not sure why you would want to.  I'd suggest using [IIS](http://www.iis.net/) (since you need ASP) as your web server and [configuring it to support PHP](http://php.iis.net/).  Then use [WatiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net/) or [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/), or something similar to test your sites.

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree with tvanfosson. Including a full-fledged standalone web server, and one that supports both ASP and PHP, is a tall order. It can probably be done, but I don't know if you have the manpower or resources to do it.

Your best hope would probably be to include a self-configuring web server with your application. For PHP you could just use an open source web server like Apache with the Zend Engine. I'm not so sure how you could distribute an ASP interpreter with your software.

However, I think a more practical solution is to simply do what Dreamweaver and most other HTML editors/web development tools do. Since the user would likely already have access to a web server, you could just have them supply the login information for the SFTP/SCP and have the application upload the code to the remote or local server for testing.